# Can't bind to 'article' since it isn't a known property of 'reddit' Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Getting an error in console: Can't bind to 'article' since it isn't a known property of 'reddit'

Reddit.component.ts
[image]

app.component.html
[image]

also even tried putting same code in reddit.component.html

[image]

But the results are same.
Sorry I am very new to angular2. Learning stage

Help me on this!!!

Comment: Always post your original code rather than an image

Comment: Well, look at that component with that selector. Does it have that property as an input to bind to? Then why did you think it would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the **`ngFor`** from the **`app.component.html`**

it will be,

```
<reddit [article]="article"></article>
```

so you are passing the article to the child component reddit , so you need to define the input on the reddit component.

```
@Input() article: Article[];
```

Comment: don't use <reddit > inside the reddit component itself

Comment: <div class="ui grid posts">
        *ngFor="let article of articles"
        [article]="article">
    </div>   Like this??

Comment: <div class="ui grid posts"> <div *ngFor="let artObj of article" >{{artObj}} </div>

Comment: Unexpected closing tag "reddit". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.